# InvalidDataException in ExtractAccessTokenFromBodyForm on an action which doesnt use OpenIdDict

Tags: openiddict

I have an action in my API which doesn't use OpenIdDict for a client to POST to. However, whenever they post an InvalidDataException is thrown in ExtractAccessTokenFromBodyForm because 'Form key length limit 2048 exceeded.'

I've tried adding a custom Authentication scheme just for this controller/action and also custom authorization but it still throws the exception. From what I've read in the code it seems that it will always intercept messages before it hits the controller/action. I'm not really sure what else I can try, any guidance would be great.

On all of my endpoints which do use OpenIdDict, they all work fine and have no issues.

Here's the stack trace if it helps

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormPipeReader.ThrowKeyTooLargeException (Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormPipeReader.ParseFormValuesFast (Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormPipeReader.ParseFormValues (Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormPipeReader+<ReadFormAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature+<InnerReadFormAsync>d__17.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ExtractAccessTokenFromBodyForm+<HandleAsync>d__3.MoveNext (OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher+<DispatchAsync>d__4`1.MoveNext (OpenIddict.Validation, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher+<DispatchAsync>d__4`1.MoveNext (OpenIddict.Validation, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandler+<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__4.MoveNext (OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35a561290d20de2f)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<AuthenticateAsync>d__48.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<AuthenticateAsync>d__14.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware+<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI, Version=6.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4232c99127b3c254)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger, Version=6.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=62657d7474907593)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Typsy.Api.Startup+<>c+<<Configure>b__8_0>d.MoveNext (Typsy.Api, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\Typsy.Api\Startup.cs:258)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware+<<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Core applies a bunch of security checks to ensure the data sent via formURL is safe to process: in this case, you're hitting a limit because you sent a key/value pair in your form with an absurdly long key (more than 2K chars).

If you're absolutely sure you need such a long key length, you can override the default value in `FormOptions`. E.g:

```cs
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => options.KeyLengthLimit = 10_000);
```